# Before distributing - Test tables & what filetype?

Tags: ms-access

I have completed my database, but have just deleted extra tables that were used in testing and design stages.  I have had a look at 'Allen Browne's Database Issue Checker', but was wondering if there was anything I should be looking at that will tell me:

- if there are extra tables in the database that won't get used;
- if there are any tables missing;
- if there is anything extra in the VBA (it compiles okay)

I was going to distribute the frontend as a .mdb file.  I have coded limitations in so that basic users are restricted in what they can access.

```
        ChangeProperty "AllowShortcutMenus", dbBoolean, False
        ChangeProperty "AllowBreakIntoCode", dbBoolean, False
        ChangeProperty "AllowSpecialKeys", dbBoolean, False
        ChangeProperty "AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, False
        ChangeProperty "AllowBuiltinToolbars", dbBoolean, False
        ChangeProperty "AllowFullMenus", dbBoolean, False
        ChangeProperty "AllowToolbarChanges", dbBoolean, False
        ChangeProperty "AllowMenuChanges", dbBoolean, False
        ChangeProperty "StartupShowDBWindow", dbBoolean, False
        DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
```

Can anyone see any problems with this or should I be using mde or accde filetypes?

Comment: if possible always compile it to MDE / ACCDE please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to do this via VBA when Access gives you, the developer, [the ability](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Customize-and-lock-the-Navigation-Pane-772605e2-2a29-4c05-a521-aa53f33d9b01) to restrict these things via GUI.

As for the file format, Microsoft highlights some of the important features that work/won't work/are missing from both versions. I suggest [looking it over](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Which-Access-file-format-should-I-use-012d9ab3-d14c-479e-b617-be66f9070b41) and gauge which file format works for you.

As for the other part of your question, there is no tool that will run all of your queries/modules/macros in order to identify a missing table or reference. I would do all of your adequate testing and keep a spreadsheet with all of your Access Objects and what their role/importance is, and verify they exist and do their job, and on what the most recent date you validated them is. This gives you an 'audit' and gives you some comfortability.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I started this project as a complete beginner using AccessXP, then we got upgraded to Access2013.

I wanted 3 levels of user, but could restrict the rights to 2 levels (Admin and Basic) and hide the remainder based on a stored userlevel value.  I'll take a look at the links you provided but it seems that I can only create a MDE file (converted the default 2000 filetype to 2002/03).

I'll also need to look at certificates I think - when I deploy this to other users they will keep getting the 'Trusted Source' warning message.  Not sure what to do about that.

Thanks again.

Comment: That's controlled in part by you. You may need select `Allow trusted locations on my network (not recommended)` checkbox.